# How to fix "failed to unpack image on snapshotter overlayfs: unexpected media type text/html" when MicroK8S is starting a deployment?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microk8s

I continue down the frustratingly stop-start road of learning Kubernetes (specifically MicroK8S).

I build an image locally on a development laptop thus:

```
docker build -t k8s-workload .
```

This is a simple PHP web app that reports some request metadata. It builds successfully:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  13.82kB
Step 1/5 : FROM php:8.2-cli-alpine
 ---> c5f1f9770838
Step 2/5 : WORKDIR /root
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 492c997c963b
Step 3/5 : RUN apk update && apk upgrade
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f91505d5fe68
Step 4/5 : COPY src /root
 ---> 02bcc72dfc97
Step 5/5 : CMD ["sh", "/root/bin/start-server.sh"]
 ---> Running in 6bc3b72365e4
Removing intermediate container 6bc3b72365e4
 ---> 0c8a405b06af
Successfully built 0c8a405b06af
Successfully tagged k8s-workload:latest
```

I create a tarball from this so it can be sent to my three-node cluster:

```
docker save k8s-workload > k8s-workload.docker.tar
```

I then send it to the leader in the cluster (though I assume it could be sent to any of them):

```
scp k8s-workload.docker.tar 192.168.50.251:/home/myuser/
```

This is all looking good so far. Now I want to [sideload](https://microk8s.io/docs/sideload) the image into all nodes in the cluster:

```
root@arran:/home/myuser# microk8s images import < k8s-workload.docker.tar
Pushing OCI images to 192.168.50.251:25000
Pushing OCI images to 192.168.50.135:25000
Pushing OCI images to 192.168.50.74:25000
```

With that looking successful, I tried to create a workload:

```
root@arran:/home/myuser# microk8s kubectl create deployment k8s-workload --image=k8s-workload
```

Finally let's get the status of this pod:

```
root@arran:/home/myuser# microk8s kubectl get pods
NAME                            READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
k8s-workload-6cdfbb6b59-zvgrl   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          35m
```

OK, that doesn't look good. There was also an error of ErrImagePull, but that seems to have been replaced now.

How can I debug why an image won't start?

I discovered a way to list the images on a node. I have found my newly built image on the leader node:

```
root@arran:/home/myuser# microk8s ctr images list | grep workload
docker.io/library/k8s-workload:latest   application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json    sha256:725b...582b 103.5 MiB linux/amd64
```

So the image is available. I can get some logs on the problem, but it does not reveal anything that I don't already know:

```
root@arran:/home/myuser# microk8s kubectl logs k8s-workload-1cdfaa6c49-zvgrl
Error from server (BadRequest): container "k8s-workload" in pod "k8s-workload-1cdfaa6c49-zvgrl" is waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image
```

What can I try next? No node would actually need to pull an image, as far as I know, since they are all available on each node.

### Update 1

I was hesitant to add too many problems to the one question, but on balance I think they are worth adding, since they are all obstacles to obtaining one result: successfully deploying a trivial workload on K8S.

When describing the single pod within the single deployment, I noticed it showed me this error:

> kubelet does not have ClusterDNS IP configured and cannot create Pod using "ClusterFirst" policy. Falling back to "Default" policy.

Yikes! Another thing that doesn't work out of the box. I have fixed this the MicroK8S way using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59550723). It hasn't solved the problem, but at least I am knocking the roadblocks on the head, one by one.

### Update 2

I wanted to check that the side-loaded image was valid, so I did this on the leader:

```
root@arran:/home/myuser# docker load < k8s-workload.docker.tar
```

That unpacks fine:

```
bb01bd7e32b5: Loading layer [==================================================>]  7.618MB/7.618MB
e759f13eb8bc: Loading layer [==================================================>]  6.015MB/6.015MB
1a72c946ba2b: Loading layer [==================================================>]  12.29kB/12.29kB
9bbacedbd5e4: Loading layer [==================================================>]  6.144kB/6.144kB
53b5e1394bc2: Loading layer [==================================================>]  12.08MB/12.08MB
aff825926dad: Loading layer [==================================================>]  4.096kB/4.096kB
c76bce6229c6: Loading layer [==================================================>]   71.7MB/71.7MB
0503c7346508: Loading layer [==================================================>]   12.8kB/12.8kB
8c2f9e7d94bb: Loading layer [==================================================>]  65.54kB/65.54kB
7e0ad9ed4982: Loading layer [==================================================>]  10.97MB/10.97MB
b99f234d8751: Loading layer [==================================================>]  5.632kB/5.632kB
Loaded image: k8s-workload:latest
```

I then run it on the leader on a custom port (i.e. this is in Docker, not K8S):

```
root@arran:/home/myuser# docker run -p 9000:80 -it k8s-workload
```

This responds via cURL as I would expect from another machine on the LAN.

### Update 3

It occurred to me that the "namespaced" image name might a different - should I be specifying `docker.io/library/k8s-workload:latest` rather than `k8s-workload`? I tried both, and I find I get the same result.

So here is the latest error:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  4m46s                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/k8s-workload-68c899df98-qhmhr to yamazaki
  Normal   Pulling    3m17s (x4 over 4m45s)  kubelet            Pulling image "k8s-workload"
  Warning  Failed     3m15s (x4 over 4m43s)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "k8s-workload": rpc error: code = NotFound desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/library/k8s-workload:latest": failed to unpack image on snapshotter overlayfs: unexpected media type text/html for sha256:e823...45c8: not found
  Warning  Failed     3m15s (x4 over 4m43s)  kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed     2m52s (x6 over 4m43s)  kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   BackOff    2m37s (x7 over 4m43s)  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "k8s-workload"
```

OK, so I now have a bit more detail. What does the "failed to unpack image" error actually mean?

### Update 4

A helpful answer below suggests that I might need to set a pull policy to get K8S to expect the image to be available on each node, and that it should not try to pull them (it does not exist anywhere remotely).

However when taking the supplied advice, although I get a different error code (`CreateContainerError`), the underlying cause is the same:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age               From               Message
  ----     ------     ----              ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  64s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/k8s-workload to yamazaki
  Normal   Pulled     6s (x7 over 62s)  kubelet            Container image "k8s-workload" already present on machine
  Warning  Failed     6s (x7 over 62s)  kubelet            Error: failed to create containerd container: error unpacking image: unexpected media type text/html for sha256:1f2c...753e1: not found
```

### Update 5

I have [reported this as a bug](https://github.com/canonical/microk8s/issues/4029) for now, though I would still welcome answers here.

### Update 6

On the basis that dogged levels of persistence is mysteriously good for the soul, I tried deleting the image using the `ctr` subcommand. This is on a follower node:

```
root@yamazaki:/home/myuser# microk8s ctr images rm docker.io/library/k8s-workload:latest
docker.io/library/k8s-workload:latest
```

Then using the same subcommand I reimported:

```
root@yamazaki:/home/myuser# microk8s ctr images import k8s-workload.docker.tar 
unpacking docker.io/library/k8s-workload:latest (sha256:725b...582b)...done
```

Since this operates at the node level and not the cluster, I did this for each of the three nodes.

I then used the `run` command, since this permits a pull policy to be set, and I don't want to conflate the unpack problem with a pull problem on top. This is back on the cluster leader:

```
root@arran:/home/myuser# microk8s kubectl run k8s-workload --image=k8s-workload --image-pull-policy='Never' --port=80
pod/k8s-workload created
```

I then describe the resulting pod, and get a familiar error:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age               From               Message
  ----     ------     ----              ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  36s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/k8s-workload to yamazaki
  Normal   Pulled     6s (x5 over 35s)  kubelet            Container image "k8s-workload" already present on machine
  Warning  Failed     6s (x5 over 35s)  kubelet            Error: failed to create containerd container: error unpacking image: unexpected media type text/html for sha256:5f76...a3aa: not found
```

Paradoxically this is reassuring - sending an image to each node individually is a right hassle, and thus I'd want the cluster level image import to work. I suspect it will once I have got to the bottom of the unpack problem.

### Update 7

Right, I have spotted something. The image tarball on all nodes has an identical checksum, as one would expect. But when it is imported, one node reports the wrong type against the image. These are lightly reformatted for ease of comparison:

Node "Arran":

```
docker.io/library/k8s-workload:latest  
application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json  
sha256:725b...582b 103.5 MiB  
linux/amd64  
io.cri-containerd.image=managed
```

Node "Yamazaki":

```
docker.io/library/k8s-workload:latest  
text/html  
sha256:5f76...a3aa 218.4 KiB  
-  
io.cri-containerd.image=managed
```

Node "Nikka":

```
docker.io/library/k8s-workload:latest  
application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json  
sha256:725b...582b 103.5 MiB  
linux/amd64  
io.cri-containerd.image=managed
```

It looks like the workloads consistently were elected to run on Yamazaki, and that's the node with the corrupted image. Now to reimport the image and get it to match the others...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final update hints at the problem - one node had a corrupted image. By coincidence this was the node on which K8S wanted to run the workload. All I had to do to fix this was to reimport the image locally:

```
root@yamazaki:/home/myuser# microk8s ctr images import k8s-workload.docker.tar 
unpacking docker.io/library/k8s-workload:latest (sha256:725b...582b)...done
```

As per the question updates, I imported this image in two ways, both involving MicroK8S:

- `microk8s images` that does a global cluster import
- `microk8s ctr images import` that does a per-node import

I think I can say, with a high degree of certainty, that MicroK8S or containerd corrupted the image (i.e. it cannot be blamed on scp or erroneous file handling). For the per-node import I verified the local tarball with `sha256sum`, and it was the same as all the others. Unfortunately I expect that this is no longer an investigable bug, given that the exact history of commands is now so complex it can be considered as lost.

That said, I will try zapping the image from all containerd instances, and using the cluster importer again. It is possible that the bug might be triggered again.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59980445/setting-image-pull-policy-using-kubectl

`kubectl run` will take `--image-pull-policy` as a cmdline argument

Comment: Thanks. It looks like this command will create a pod, but not a deployment. I don't know the difference between `run` and `create deployment` yet, but no matter - it still does not work. I am getting the two errors added in comments under the question (I am hesitant to add too much to the question, as I'd rather write a good general question that is helpful to others, rather than a unique situation that no-one will ever have again).

Comment: Update: I don't think it's a pull policy problem. It looks like something is having difficulty with unpacking the image, despite it working fine in Docker. What further things can I try?

Comment: I've added a bunch of updates to the question, and have refrained thus far from chucking the laptop out of the window 